# Al intentar guardar un dato en la variable totalInteres, no se guarda y queda con el valor de 0

Tags: java

Sucede que al intentar guardar el total de intereses en la variable `interesTotal`, no se guarda, y al mostrarla queda su valor en `0`. No pasa con la variable `totalCapital`, esa si muestra correctamente su valor.

---

```
public class Interes {
       double interesTotal,totalCapital,interes;
       Datos obj = new Datos();
       public void Calculos(){
           obj.pedirCliente();
           for(int i=0;i<obj.cantidadClientes;i++){
               obj.pedirCapital();
               obj.pedirDia();
               obj.pedirTasa();
               interes = (obj.capital*obj.tasaInteres)*((360-obj.dia)/360);
               totalCapital = obj.capital+totalCapital;
               interesTotal = interesTotal+interes;
           } 
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hola Camilo, podrías mostrarnos como creas el objeto **Interes** y como le pides los datos?, tambien la clase **Datos**, gracias.

Comment: Puede que por algún motivo `interes` sea siempre `0`. Esto es muy simple de depurar, basta con poner un `System.out.println(interes);` justo después de haber calculado el valor para esa variable y revisar la salida en consola al ejecutar el programa. Si es siempre `0`, deberás verificar lo que ocurre con este cálculo: `(obj.capital*obj.tasaInteres)*((360-obj.dia)/360)`, qué valores hay en `obj.capital`, `obj.tasaInteres` y en `obj.dia`, etc.

Comment: El problema está en la forma en que calculas el interés, más explícitamente en **(( 360 - obj.dia ) / 360 )**, `Java` interpreta que estás dividiendo `int's` y te devuelve el resultado correspondiente, osea "`0`", si cambias uno  de los "`360`" por "`360.0`" tu código funcionará.

Comment: @MarcePuente Sip, efectivamente funcionó. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Un placer ayudarte!!

Answer (score 0):

esta es la clase Datos

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Datos {
    int cantidadClientes, dia, tasaInteres,capital;
    public void pedirCliente(){
        cantidadClientes = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de clientes: "));
    }
    public void pedirDia(){
        dia = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el dia : "));
    }
    public void pedirTasa(){
        tasaInteres = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la tasa de interés: "));
    }
    public void pedirCapital(){
        capital = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la capital: "));
    }
}
```

y esta es la clase principal en la cual muestro los resultados

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Banco {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interes obj = new Interes();
        obj.Calculos();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El capital total depositado es de: "+obj.totalCapital);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El total de intereses generados es de: "+obj.interesTotal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Si vas a añadir más información, tienes que editar tu pregunta y agregarlo, no usar la sección de respuestas.